# Post method using webclient

Tags: post, windows-phone-8, webclient

It get an error api keyname is incorrect. All the parameters which were passed are correct. However, I think the way I am passing the parameters is wrong. Please suggest a solution

```
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "apikey" ,"ETG123");
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "deviceid" ,"12");
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "name" ,"arun");
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "email","arun.yva9@gmail.com");
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "dob", "10-10-1990");
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "mobileno", "9848022338");
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "country", "India");
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "companyname", "etg");
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "city", "hyderabad");
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://192.168.0.149/redington/Services/register_user", UriKind.Absolute), "POST",postData.Tostring());
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc1_UploadStringCompleted);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than appending, use '&' for adding parameters

```
string postData = string.Empty;
postData += "&apikey=ETG123";
postData +="&deviceid=12";
```

Hope this will help you.